# How to create a prompt in Google Apps Script for a webapp that I can use to embed in a Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I want visitors to my site to type their company name. How they do that, in a form, javascript app, web app, or other - I don't care. I want to take that input and generate a link. That link will be /customer input/.mydomain.com. Thats it! Everything I have tried fails. The best solution was a script saved as a web app that works great until I launch it from my Google Site. Then I get errors around the promptbox. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Alerts/prompts appear to be blocked so anything I create in html, javascript or webapp fails.
I tried a simple sheet that takes the input in one cell then uses hyperlink formula to generate the link, but that is un-editable from the site.

One note, when I created a web app using app script and ran it in the sheet, it worked perfectly. After publishing it and embedding in my site, nothing. Developer mode shows me an error due to (I'm assuming) Google Sites blocking alerts/popups.

I do appreciate any guidance and/or information anyone can provide!

This simple app script, as an example, works in a Google Sheet, but not when I save it as a web app and embed it into a Google Site.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CompanyName');
}

function CompanyName() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var prompt=ui.prompt("Company Name", "Please enter your company name", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  var response=prompt.getResponseText();
  var button=prompt.getSelectedButton();
```

I want someone to enter /company name/. Then I want to take that input and generate a link to /company name/.mydomain.com. This has to happen within a Google Sites webpage.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How does your 'CompanyName' html file look like? I'm assuming you are not trying to reference the 'CompanyName' function here because it's incorrect. Also, why do you expect the UI object to get instantiated from your website? The 'ui' variable references the open spreadsheet UI and has nothing to do with html

Comment: Like Anton said, you should do this with html and not sheets specific ui prompts.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply and information. Anton, thank you for the welcome! I'm sure you are both right in that I am using sheets specific ui prompts. My question then is how do I get the functionality (a prompt, input and URL creation) to work as part of a webapp independent of a sheets prompt? The following is my html file.

Comment: <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Company Name</h1>
        
        <button onclick="PromptBox()">Enter Company Name</button>
        
        <ul id="courses"></ul>
        
        <script>
        function PromptBox() {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        })
        .withFailureHandler(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        })
        .PromptBox();
        }
        
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>